# Understanding how git diff & git cherry-pick works

Tags: git, github, version-control

Here is the repro repo: https://github.com/sathishsoundharajan/git-diff

Steps

1. Created new repository in github.
2. Created master branch.
3. Added master.txt file to master branch and committed.
4. Created new branch named feature-branch from master.
5. Added feature.txt file to feature branch and committed.
6. Switch to master branch.
7. Added a new file new-master.txt to master branch and committed ( CommitId: https://github.com/sathishsoundharajan/git-diff/commit/593da755a9ea90b6f55bcc6d184f249218bf4170)
8. Now for some reason let's say i have to cherry-pick this commit to feature-branch.
9. Switch to feature-branch.
10. Use `git cherry-pick 593da755a9ea90b6f55bcc6d184f249218bf4170`. Cherry-picked without conflicts but the commit_id changed to https://github.com/sathishsoundharajan/git-diff/commit/e58427c82322d6a3ec933741887f5b8312981e11
11. Now if we raise a pull request from feature-branch to master / take git diff between master and feature-branch, i should only see the feature.txt file alone in the diff. But i can see new-master.txt file also in the diff
    https://github.com/sathishsoundharajan/git-diff/pull/1

Questions:

1. Why commit-id changed after cherry-pick ?
2. Can we stop cherry-pick to not create new commit-id and reuse the existing one ?
3. Why in git diff i'm seeing new-master.txt even though it is already in the master branch ?
4. Is there way to make git does not show this diff ?
5. Is there a way to see diff between two branches without comparing commit-ids and by comparing actual change in the files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 because history is different so the IDs can't be the same for security/cryptographic reasons.

2 no, related ro #1 ... if you got the same ID, that would mean you found a collision (or you are producing the exact same objects, like what `git svn` does)... theoretically possible but....

3 because in PR/MR, you see differences not between the tips of the two branches but since the *feature branch is started*, say (what you get if you try `git diff` with `...` instead of `..`). If you saw the differences between the 2 tlps of the branches, code review would be hell because you would see changes from the MR/PR itself plus the changes introduced in the target branch since the MR/PR branch was started (not to name that the changes will change over time as more stuff is merged unto the target branch). Who would want to work like that?

4 like the diff betwern the 2 branch tips? Try with `..` instead of `...`. Now, on github? They *might* provide the option if they considered it necessay but I don't think you will find a lot of customers would be interested.... *and* then it's about them, not about git.

5 what do you mean?

Comment: `git diff master..feature-branch` - shows only feature.txt file.  `git diff master...feature-branch` - shows both feature.txt and new-master.txt file

Comment: Right.... because the other file was added in the branch _after_ it diverged from master (actually it was added in master too, right? But that does not matter if you use `...`). So?

Comment: I need the output of `git diff master..feature-branch` - this one shows exact diff between master and feature-branch, i guess this one does changes comparison not the commit-id diffs. This one `git diff master...feature-branch` does commit-id level comparison i guess even though the new-master.txt file is in both master and feature branch it shows up in the diff

Comment: They do the same thing... they _diff_. What `...` does differently is that it first finds (roughly) the last common ancestor of the branches you are comparing and then compares with the second branch provided (which is what you probably want to do when attempting code review in a PR/MR).

Comment: `..` should also work but in a very narrow scope. It will make it difficult to do code review if there are things merged into the target branch after the feature branch is started.